# Trouble in strstr() to get string after sub-string in C

Tags: c, parsing, text-parsing, strstr

Currently working on developing parser using C.
I wanted to extract portion of lines after a specific character set. For example, from following line "Target" need to be extracted.

`"V {  <Target> ;"`

Now I use strstr() to locate lines contains "V {  ", succeeded. but unable to remove "V {  " portion to get clean target. usually strstr() supports sizeof() to make pointer beginning of "Target". But my code return nothing while using sizeof(). My code is below, thanks for your time.

```
while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, textfile)){
    const char *p1 = strstr(line, "V {  ");        // end of this line may include offset "+5", didn't work 
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, ";");              // returns nothing using this code.
        if (p1 != NULL){                                                   
           size_t len = p2-p1;
           char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
           strncpy(res, p1, len);
           res[len] = '\0';
           printf("%s\n", res);
           }
     }
```

Comment: add something along `p1 = p1 + strlen("V {  ")`. `p1` points to the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt you're right, I deleted my comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p1 points to the start of the match.
Add an offset to p1 to get rid of what you do not need.

```
strncpy(res, p1+3, len-3);
res[len-3] = '\0';
```

(3 can be some other offset, depending on what you want).

Comment: Thanks for  your quick solution. Now able to use sizeof() to pass offset information to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, you may want to define your own function that increments the pointer to the start of the matched substring by the length of the search string, thus giving you the contents of the target string *after* the search string.

`strcspn` can be used to find the *span* (length of bytes) between the initial argument and the first character encountered that can be found in its second argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *str_after(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    const char *start = strstr(haystack, needle);

    return start ? start + strlen(needle) : NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *val = str_after("hello world;\n", "hello ");

    if (val) {
        size_t len = strcspn(val, ";");
        char *copy = malloc(1 + len);

        if (copy) {
            memcpy(copy, val, len);
            copy[len] = '\0';
            puts(copy);
            free(copy);
        }
    }
}
```

```
world
```

---

Some things of note from your example:

In

```
const char *p1 = strstr(line, "V {  ");
const char *p2 = strstr(p1, ";");
```

if `p1` is `NULL`, then the second call to `strsr` invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

> *usually strstr() supports sizeof() to make pointer beginning of [sic]*

The [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) *operator* resolves to the size of an *object* or type in *bytes*. It has no inherent relationship with `strstr`.

It sounds like you have used `sizeof` on an *array* object in the past and are confused by the results of using `sizeof` on a *pointer* object, which of course will give you the size of the pointer itself, regardless of what it points to.

On that note, `sizeof (char)` is **guaranteed** to be `1`.

Don't forget you need to `free` every pointer returned by `malloc` when you are finished using the memory, or you will be leaking memory constantly.

Comment: I am confused because, outside while loop following code works.   const char *p1 = srtstr(line, START)+sizeof(OFFSET). But when use with loops as in my question, returns NULL.